# cannot execute the following sql query because of permission 

Tags: sql, sql-server

What level of rights would i need to execute the following query ?

```
SELECT S.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests R
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions S
ON S.session_id = R.blocking_session_id

sys.dm_exec_sessions is a Dynamic Management view
```

i am getting an error saying that it cant start debugger;

Comment: please tell me what is chatspeak ?

Comment: cos instead of because, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language)

Comment: It isn't that we don't have a sense of humor, or that we want you to type a lot. But we discourage chatspeak because it is already difficult enough for people whose native language is not English to understand what we are saying here. Slang just makes it harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [very helpful article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=179):

These DM Views are secured, since they might show information you'd rather not have available to everyone.

Grant the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission for server-level and `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permissions for database-level Dynamic Management Views and Functions. It's usually best to create a Role and then  grant the permissions to that.

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO <<login name>>
```

Answer (score 1):

[VIEW SERVER STATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx)

As per the relevant MSDN pages for the Dynamic Management Views: [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx), [Two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

i hope you are using Debug instead of Execute(F5).

Comment: How is this answer relevant please?